# Audio on Firefox doesn't work after using Hydrogen

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am new to Ubuntu and just installed Ubuntu Studio. After Googling a previous audio problem regarding no sound on Youtube, I uninstalled pulseaudio. Audio works fine both on Youtube and Hydrogen on their own. But I've found that after using Hydrogen, the audio is cut off from everything else after closing it. (Skype, Firefox)

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to restart pulseaudio and alsa...To restart pulseaudio through

```
pulseaudio --start
and 
sudo alsa force-reload
```

There also may be a problem with Jack if you are using it. Jack and pulseaudio often run into conflict with eachother when they both try to hit the same soundcard at the same time. I would suggest checking this if you are using Jack along with pulseaudio.

http://jackaudio.org/pulseaudio_and_jack

Hope this helps.

Comment: You might need to kill pulseaudio first with pulseaudio --kill

Comment: I ended up reinstalling with 12.04 LTS 64-bit. Thank you for your help.

Comment: sudo alsa force-reload did the trick for me, and I would like to fix this permanently, but your link is broken.